# Renaming and moving channel to a different category with a command

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a small script that when I run `!chan *channel name* *channel new name*` it will rename the channel to the new name.

My question is in 2 parts, is there a way to have it so I can just type `!chan *channel new name*` and it will rename the current channel?

And is there a way to move the channel to a different category that I already have on the server when I run that same command, for example.

`!chan test1` will rename the channel to "test1" but also move it from category A to category B.

```
@client.command()
async def chan(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel, *, new_name):
    await channel.edit(name=new_name)
```

Hope you can help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To move it to a new category, try:

```
B = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name="category B")
await ctx.channel.edit(category=B)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.position
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.edit position - The new channel’s position.