# Changing category for a text channel via discord.py library

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I tried

```py
async def movechannel(ctx,channel:discord.TextChannel):
await channel.edit(category="FINISHED")
    print("working")
```

it prints `working` but doesn't change the category.

Comment: Welcome @Moby772! Check out [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), this question needs to be improved with a minimal example and more context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Renaming and moving channel to a different category with a command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64200134/renaming-and-moving-channel-to-a-different-category-with-a-command)